# Find closest triangle plane to point using cKDTree query

Tags: python, numpy, closest, kdtree

I'm trying to find a closest triangle plane to a point using `cKDTree query`.

I already know to find a closest neighbor to the point. Example:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import numpy as np

p1 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
p2 = np.array([[100, 100, 100],
               [670, 500, 890],
               [666, 456, 765]])

tuple_dist_neighbor = cKDTree(p2).query(p1)
print(tuple_dist_neighbor) # prints (173.20508075688772, 0)
```

So the `return` value is a tuple of the distance to the closest neighbor and the index of the closest neighbor.

Now let's say i have two triangles, each one built of 3 points. Example:

```
triangle1 = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 4, 0],
                      [4, 0, 4]])

triangle2 = np.array([[100, 100, 100],
                      [100, 140, 100],
                      [140, 100, 140]])

triangle_set = np.array([triangle1, triangle2])

point = np.array([10, 11, 12])
```

So i'm wondering if its possible to find the closest triangle to the point using cKDTree like above.

The triangles i'm dealing with are forming a mesh all together.

[Picture 1: Mesh formed of triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ww4A.png)

And the real problem is to find the closest triangle in this mesh to a point.

Comment: Do the triangles have any relationship to each other? (i.e. Do the form a mesh? Are they a convex hull or delaunay simplices of a cloud of points?) - if they are arbitrary, you're sort of out of luck and will likely need to brute force it.

Comment: Yes they do. I edited my post.